# insert on duplicate key update with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, insert-update

When using [insert... on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), what is the syntax to update multiple columns and not update some columns?

**i wrote the following query:**

```
INSERT INTO table (id,number,text) VALUES (1,2,3),(3,5,"i want this remain the previous value and not change"),(1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), number=VALUES(number), text=VALUES(text);
```

how to not change some values and let them remain it's previous value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with `IF`:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,number,text) VALUES (1,2,3),(3,5,"ZZZ"),(1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), number=VALUES(number), text=IF(VALUES(text)="ZZZ", text, VALUES(text));
```

-for multiple values use `IN` instead of `=`:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,number,text) VALUES (1,2,3),(3,5,"ZZZ"),(1,2,"YYY")
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), number=VALUES(number), text=IF(VALUES(text) IN ("ZZZ", "YYY"), text, VALUES(text));
```

Comment: can you say me how to use `IN` instead of `=`